# Is there a way to generate multiple files/classes with intellij code/file templates?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-generation, vtl

I like intellij's code/file templates, they are working really well for me for single files but it would be great to be able to create multiple files/classes at once.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142937/does-intellij-support-any-kind-of-templating-to-create-multiple-files-automatica) but since it has been a few years since I was hoping that things might have changed.

We are using the mvp pattern in our application so every time we want to create a new view, it requires two classes and two interfaces, which are always in the same pattern. It would be awesome if we could generate all of the infrastructure for this and link up the classes.

Any suggestions or new information would be appreciated?
Maybe it is time to log a feature request with [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com)?

Comment: Feature request http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-5351

Comment: tons of classes make me think of struts... may be you can write a tool to generate multi files, and may be a mvp2 with less class files will appears to replace it.

Comment: This feature has finally been developed and is scheduled for release in the 2020.3 EAP. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91565

Answer (score 8):

This feature seems to be available in [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Multifile.html) (another `JetBrains` IDE). It still does not seem possible in `IDEA` yet.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment IDE doesn't support this feature. Most popular youtrack [request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-5351)  have 60+ votes, but it still opened(since 2012). You can use 3rd party solution, for example [this](https://github.com/CeH9/PackageTemplates) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible (now). See below links.

https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-template-group-android-studiointellij/
https://medium.com/codequest/file-group-templates-in-android-studio-unofficial-guide-85dfa0a0c1ec

Comment: This is for android studio. Can the same be done in intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that using JavaParser but I am not sure how you could invoke it from the IDEA interface

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for this,

Open the desired file in the editor.
On the main menu, choose Tools | Save File as Template.
In the File and Code Templates dialog box that opens specify the new template name and edit the source code, if necessary.save changes and close the dialog box.